# Random Distance on Torus

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, convolution

Let $U=(X_U, Y_U)$ and $V=(X_V, Y_V)$ be two independent random points in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$, where each possible position is equally likely.

Now I am interested in the probability that these two random chosen points have distance $\leq r$ on the torus.

The distance on the torus is defined as $$d(U,V)=\sqrt{\min(|X_U-X_V|, 1-|X_U- X_V|)^2 + \min(|Y_U-Y_V|, 1-|Y_U- Y_V|)^2}.$$

I tried to do the following, using $A:=\min(|X_U-X_V|, 1-|X_U- X_V|), B:=\min(|Y_U-Y_V|, 1-|Y_U- Y_V|)$,

$$P[d(U,V)\leq r]=P[A^2+B^2 \leq r^2]=\int_{0}^{r^2} P[A^2=t]P[B^2\leq r^2-t]\text{d}t$$ $$=\int_{0}^{r^2} \int_{0}^{r^2-t} P[A^2=t]P[B^2=s] \text{d}s \text{d}t.$$

But I have no idea how to calculate $A^2$ and $B^2$.

Intuitively, I would say that the probability is the area of a circle of radius $r$, which is $r^2 \pi$.

So would really appreciate any hint of you! Thank you very much.

Comment: Hint: given the symmetry of the problem, do both $U$ and $V$ really need to be random? Could you just translate the torus to put $U$ in a convenient spot?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. So taking together your comments/answers, I see that I should try to translate the torus such that $U$ is placed in $(1/2, 1/2)$. Then we always have that $A=|X_U-X_V|$ and $B=|Y_U-Y_V|$. Now I see that this is the right answer, but could one derive this formally? So how does on state this transformation of the torus and the fact that the probability is the intersection formally?

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone could give me an idea how to prove this formally (only based on simple probability theory). 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Note that because the metric is translation-invariant, you can assume WLOG that $U = (1/2,1/2)$, say.  If $0 \le x \le 1$ and $0 \le y \le 1$, the distance from $(x,y)$ to $(1/2,1/2)$ on the torus is the same as the Euclidean distance.
So the probability that $d(U,V) \le r$ is just the area of the intersection of the circle of radius $r$ centred at $(1/2,1/2)$ with the square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$.

Comment: which is a circle if $r\le \frac12$ and a circle less four congruent segments if $\frac12 \lt r \lt 1$